# stop that div from moving-animation css3

Tags: html, css, animation

Ok..so i have a problem about an animation in css3: i made 4 divs with an animation that move them left and the down and another div that is moved down by those 4...i want that div to stay fixed there where it is. Here is the part of the css3 code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes anim{
    0% {background-color:#333399; margin-top:16px; margin-left: 20px;}
    25% {background-color:#336699; margin-top:16px; margin-left:190px;}
    50% {background-color:#339999; margin-top:91px; margin-left:190px;}
    75% {background-color:33CC99; margin-top:91px; margin-left:20px;}
    100% {background-color:#333399; margin-top:16px; margin-left:20px;}
    }
    .anim{
    height:70px;
    width:110px;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 35px 0 0 0;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    color:#F0F0F0;
    -webkit-animation-name: anim;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    #content{
    background-color:#CCFFFF;
    height:800px;
    width:550px;
    margin-left:400px;
    margin-top:-400px;
    position:absolute;
    }

<div class="anim">bla</div>
<div class="anim">blabla</div>
<div class="anim">blablabla</div>
<div class="anim">blablablabla</div>
<div id="content"><div>
```

that is the part of the html code

Comment: ! we'll need the HTML code at - least or a fiddle .

Comment: No javascript? Like Alex said, please make a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the position of div#content only with margins. It will follow the position of its precedent sibling. 
Using `top` property allow to set its position independently of your animations.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes anim{
    0% {background-color:#333399; margin-top:16px; margin-left: 20px;}
    25% {background-color:#336699; margin-top:16px; margin-left:190px;}
    50% {background-color:#339999; margin-top:91px; margin-left:190px;}
    75% {background-color:33CC99; margin-top:91px; margin-left:20px;}
    100% {background-color:#333399; margin-top:16px; margin-left:20px;}
    }
    .anim{
    height:70px;
    width:110px;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 35px 0 0 0;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    color:#F0F0F0;
    -webkit-animation-name: anim;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    #content{
    background-color:#CCFFFF;
    height:800px;
    width:550px;
    margin-left:400px;
    top:16px;
    position:absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div class="anim">bla</div>
<div class="anim">blabla</div>
<div class="anim">blablabla</div>
<div class="anim">blablablabla</div>
<div id="content"><div>
```